# Importación de módulos y python2/python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Resulta que tengo hecho un paquete que me funciona perfectamente en **python2**, pero quiero hacerlo compatible con **python3** y me he encontrado con un problema que no sé muy bien cómo resolver.

Simplificando mucho todo, el problema se puede exponer así:

```
+-- prueba.py
+-- prueba
      |
      +--- __init__.py
      +--- b.py
      +--- c.py
```

1. **__init__.py** contiene unos cuantos `from .fichero import *` para hacer accesibles algunas clases.
2. **b.py** necesita una clase que hay en **c.py**.
3. **c.py** necesita una clase que hay definida en **b.py**

En **python2** me funciona la siguiente solución:

**prueba.py**: *Programa de prueba*:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import prueba

print(prueba.func_c())
```

**__init__.py**:

```
from .b import *
```

**b.py**:

```
from .c import func_c

def func_b():
    return "Hola"
```

**c.py**:

```
import b 

def func_c():
    return b.func_b()
```

Sin embargo en python3 no funciona el `import b`, porque ya no se permiten las importaciones relativas hechas así. El problema es que importaciones del tipo:

```
from .b import func_c
```

o bien:

```
from . import b
```

no funcionan porque hay una referencia circular. ¿Alguna solución?

**Actualización**

He comprobado que sí funciona la siguiente línea en **c.py**:

```
import prueba.b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi opinión, más que un problema con python3, lo que tienes es un problema de *"referencias circulares"* entre módulos. Mi recomendación es que "desacoples" los módulos metiendo el `import` dentro del *scope* de la función que lo usa:

**c.py:**

```
def func_c():
    from .b import func_b
    return func_b()
```

Tener un único *`import` global* al principio del código es más una norma de estilo que de eficiencia. Python no reimporta los módulos que ya ha importado.

Comment: Sí, es un problema de referencias cruzadas. El código real es más complicado, pero he probado a meter los import dentro de las dos funciones y el método de **c.py** y efectivamente funciona. Si eso no castiga mucho al rendimiento, me parece la mejor solución.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar la primera línea en c.py por:

```
from prueba import b
```

Comment: Seguiría habiendo una referencia circular. Lo que sí he visto que funciona es: `import prueba.b`.

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, explica lo que hiciste y la aceptas si te funciono.

Comment: Hay una cosa que no me convence del todo y no sé si existirá una respuesta mejor: en todo el paquete no he usado nunca el nombre del paquete, lo que supone que si decido cambiarlo de nombre (es decir, decido cambiar el nombre del directorio), todo sigue funcionando perfectamente. Sin embargo, si aplico esta solución me vería obligado a cambiar también esta línea.